# Join Pandas Dataframes according to array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am attempting to join several dataframes together.  The list of names of these dataframes is stored in another dataframe called `companies`, which is displayed below.

```
>>> companies
16:   Symbols
0    TUES
1    DRAM
2    NTRS
3    PCBK
4    CRIS
5    PERY
6    IRDM
7   GNCMA
8    IBOC
```

My aim would be to do something like this: `joined=TUES.join(DRAM)` then `joined=joined.join(NTRS)` and so on, down the list.  How might I be able to reference elements of the `Symbols` column of the dataframe `companies` in order to achieve this?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can define an empty `DataFrame` and append all other dataframes to it. See the example below:

```
combined_df = pandas.DataFrame()
for df in other_dataframes:
    combined_df = combined_df.append(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [pd.concat](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.tools.merge.concat.html), it is designed for merging lists of dfs:

so for your example just turn the values into a list and then concat:

```
joined = pd.concat(list(companies['Symbols']), axis=1)
```

Example:

```
In [4]:

import pandas as pd   
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.randn(5), 'b':np.random.randn(5)})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'c':np.random.randn(5), 'd':np.random.randn(5)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'e':np.random.randn(5), 'f':np.random.randn(5)})
df_list=[df,df2,df1]
df_list

Out[4]:

[          a         b
 0  0.143116  1.205407
 1 -0.430869  1.429313
 2  0.059810  0.430131
 3  2.554849 -1.450640
 4 -1.127638  0.715323

 [5 rows x 2 columns],           e         f
 0  0.658967  1.150672
 1  0.813355 -0.252577
 2  0.885928  0.970844
 3  0.519375 -1.929081
 4 -0.217152  0.907535

 [5 rows x 2 columns],           c         d
 0 -1.375885  1.422697
 1 -0.870040  0.135527
 2 -0.696600  1.954966
 3  0.494035 -0.727816
 4 -0.367156 -0.216115

 [5 rows x 2 columns]]

In [8]:
# now concatenate the list of dfs, by column
pd.concat(df_list,axis=1)

Out[8]:

          a         b         e         f         c         d
0  0.143116  1.205407  0.658967  1.150672 -1.375885  1.422697
1 -0.430869  1.429313  0.813355 -0.252577 -0.870040  0.135527
2  0.059810  0.430131  0.885928  0.970844 -0.696600  1.954966
3  2.554849 -1.450640  0.519375 -1.929081  0.494035 -0.727816
4 -1.127638  0.715323 -0.217152  0.907535 -0.367156 -0.216115

[5 rows x 6 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help again ed.  There seems to be an issue with the way I built the list, however.  companies['Symbols'] is a list of strings that are the names of dataframes, as opposed to dataframes themselves.  I did this because the list is written by a whileloop using append: `...     row=pandas.DataFrame([dict(Symbols=stock, Date=stockhistory.index[0])])` `...     companies=companies.append(row, ignore_index=True)`  I've found an awkward workaround but I'm interested: how might I write this list so it works with your technique?

Comment: sorry I'm confused by the statement that companies['Symbols'] is a list of dataframes rather than dataframes? The fact that they are strings and not dataframes is a bit confusing, are you saying that these are just names and that these dataframes don't exist? Do you just want to add the symbols column to another dataframe?